# How to Override Edit button for Custom Visualforce page based on RecordID

Tags: apex, visualforce, button-overrides

I have `Order form`,where there are `3 types of Orders(OrderScan,OrderFill,OrderGet)` for each of these i have created `Visualforce Page for new Orders(By Overriding New button)`.Based on these Record types i am redirecting to perticular VF page.

Now i am facing a problem for overriding `Edit Button`.I have also created `3 VF page` for `Editing` now i should redirect to `perticular Edit VF page based on RecordID`.How can i do this..?Please help

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the action propriety of apex:page

Create a new Visualforce page with only this line

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" action="{!URLFOR(CASE(Order__c.RecordType.Name, 'OrderScan', '/apex/vfp1' ,'OrderFill','/apex/vfp2', '/apex/vfp3'))}" >
    <apex:variable value="{!Order__c.RecordType.Name}" var="recTypeName"/>
</apex:page>
```

override your edit button with this new page.

Don't forget to change the condition and the urls and to add your standard controller (SObject you want to override the Edit button for it) :)

Comment: thanks for reply.Here what could be the value for 'value1' and 'value2'.

Comment: What are the possible values for the RecordID?

Comment: Order will have more records..as i mentioned in the question i have three different orders,i want to customize the edit screen for these three orders..

Comment: so to differentiate theme you have a RecordType ?

Comment: Yes i have order record type.

Comment: I edited the code example, of course you should replace the Order__c by your SObject API name and also the developer name of your record Types.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I will check it and let you know...

Comment: @NullReferenceException when you get a second, you should upvote this answer that led you to a possible solution.

Comment: Sure i will make it as answer..

Comment: I am getting this exception.
System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Order__c.RecordType .

Comment: I edited the code, this due to the reference of a field that neither shown in the Visualforce page nor queried by SOQL.
  and to solve this you must make a reference to the field either by using apex:variable or apex:inputHidden

Comment: Thanks.Yes its redirecting correctly.but i am not getting the edited order values in the VF page..As there are three types of order i have created 3 VF pages for edit because some fields are hidden in one page and those visible in another page.How should i do that.Thanks for your help.

Comment: in this case you have to add them as parameters to each url.  for example : /apex/vfp1?param1=value1&param2=value2  and you must add those fields into you visualforce page as we did for the RecordType.Name.

Comment: Do you have a controller (extension) for your page?