# View Button override - Redirect to a VF page or standard detail page based on Recordtype using URLFOR on page action method

Tags: redirect, button-overrides, urlfor

I need to restrict View button override based on Record type of Opportunity using page URLFOR function on page action method. Based on the record type, I need to redirect the page to standard detail page or another vf page. I tried few things, but I can't get this thing working.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  action="{!URLFOR(CASE(Opportunity.RecordType.Name, 'RecType1',  '/apex/vfpage1', 'RecType2', 'apex/vfpage1', 'RecType3', $Action.Opportunity.View, '/apex/vfpage1'), Opportunity.Id) }">
     <apex:variable value="{!Order__c.RecordType.Name}" var="recTypeName"/>-
</apex:page>
```

I used the below references:

[How to Override Edit button for Custom Visualforce page based on RecordID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33192/how-to-override-edit-button-for-custom-visualforce-page-based-on-recordid/33193#33193)

[override standard edit button based on recordtype](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63203/override-standard-edit-button-based-on-recordtype/63252)

Comment: Do you have any code to share with your question

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  action="{!URLFOR(CASE(Opportunity.RecordType.Name, 'RecType1',  '/apex/vfpage1', 'RecType2', 'apex/vfpage1', 'RecType3', $Action.Opportunity.View, '/apex/vfpage1'), Opportunity.Id) }">

Comment: Hi Santanu, I have just added the code.